# Ruby insert ENV[api_key] in script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openweathermap

In application.yml I have `api_key: 1234567890`

If I do this (inserting the api key 'appid' directly) it works (widget shows and populates):

```
<script>
  window.myWidgetParam ? window.myWidgetParam : window.myWidgetParam = [];  window.myWidgetParam.push({id: 15,cityid: '2643743',appid: '1234567890' %>,units: 'metric',containerid: 'openweathermap-widget-15',  });  (function() {var script = document.createElement('script');script.async = true;script.charset = "utf-8";script.src = "//openweathermap.org/themes/openweathermap/assets/vendor/owm/js/weather-widget-generator.js";var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);  })();
</script>
```

But if I do this (inserting `<%= ENV["api_key"] %>`) it doesn't (widget not showing due to missing quotes around the api key):

```
<script>
  window.myWidgetParam ? window.myWidgetParam : window.myWidgetParam = [];  window.myWidgetParam.push({id: 15,cityid: '2643743',appid: <%= ENV["api_key"] %>,units: 'metric',containerid: 'openweathermap-widget-15',  });  (function() {var script = document.createElement('script');script.async = true;script.charset = "utf-8";script.src = "//openweathermap.org/themes/openweathermap/assets/vendor/owm/js/weather-widget-generator.js";var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);  })();
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the name of that file and how is it rendered? I'm betting it doesn't have an `.erb` anywhere in the name.

Comment: home.html.erb ;)

Comment: Define "doesn't work". is the api key correctly rendered on the page? You may find you forgot to add something.

Comment: The followup question is indeed irrelevant / out-of-scope.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Is this out of scope: How do I keep the api key hidden?

Comment: Out of scope of the original form of this question, yes. It was about rendering problem. And "how do I keep api key hidden" is something else __entirely__.

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev I have removed that part

Comment: How did you check that `ENV["api_key"]` is actually set in your environment?

Comment: @spickermann The actual api key is shown in the HTML but since the quotes are missing it throws an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
<%== ENV['api_key'].to_json %>
```

Comment: Hmm. That inserts `&quot;1234567890&quot;` into the script!?

Comment: `==` is the ERB equivalent to [Rails' `raw` output helper method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw) that does not HTML escape the output.

Answer (score 0):

How about `appid: '<%= ENV["api_key"] %>'`?

Comment: @JohanFaerch Isn't that the point? You say it crashes because of the missing quotes. Also your first example has `appid: '1234567890'`, not `appid: 1234567890`

Comment: In your suggestion it inserts the actual code as a string and not the api key.

My 'first example' is from the yml file which has different syntax - Without quotes.

I need to get the actual api key passed inside of quotes like shown in the first script in my question.

Comment: @JohanFaerch "Just inserts <%= ENV["api_key"] %> as a string" - no, I don't think so. Must be you did something wrong while applying this answer.

Comment: Sorry. Misunderstood your last part. The first script example is the correct and working one but with the api key entered directly in the file.

Comment: From what you've told us, my best guess is that you just don't feed the file through erb at all.